# Why are some packages in the code prefixed with v2, but the file path I cloned has no v2?

Tags: go, go-modules

GitHub:https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser

When I read the source code of this project, I found that main.go relied on the cmd package. I found that the path in the import statement contains v2, but I have no v2 in the file path after I cloned the project from github? why is this happening?

```golang
package main

import (
    "runtime"

    "github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser/v2/cmd"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    cmd.Execute()
}
```

[The structure of this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOic2.png)

Comment: [The module](https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser/blob/8ec2773/go.mod) is named "github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser/v2". That is [best practice](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#semantic-import-versioning).

Comment: And `go` will check out [the latest tag beginning with `v2`](https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser/releases), instead of looking for a subfolder named `v2`

Answer (score 0):

The `github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser` repository is using the “major branch” style of code layout, which puts the `v2` variant of the module on a branch or `v2.X.Y` tag rather than in a subdirectory.

See:

- http://golang.org/wiki/Modules#releasing-modules-v2-or-higher
- https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_compatibility_and_semantic_versioning
- https://research.swtch.com/vgo-module#from_repository_to_modules